# SOAP API - Reading first line of an excel file to determine setter methods

Tags: soap-api

I want to use Java to bind to the SOAP API to insert some objects into salesforce from a CSV file. I don't want to use the dataloader or excel connector, because I will be inserting multiple related objects and will be writing code to automate the whole process with a single button press.

My CSV files have the first line defining the names of the fields that I want to insert. I want to keep my solution as flexible as possible, so I don't want to hardcode the order of the fields like the following:

```
Account acc = new Account();
acc.setId(id);
acc.setName(name);
...
```

Instead, I would like to read the first line and perhaps insert the order/name combination into a map and then use this to somehow call the right setter methods for my object (This obviously presumes that the header names are well formed).

I am stuck on how I can call a setter method, or even set a field using the dot notation, in the above scenario using the name of the field. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: How are you accessing the SOAP API...? With Java, .NET, other? You could use the reflection API in either to call the setter methods

Comment: I'm using Java. I'll have a look into this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the Partner-wsdl, you'd only have access to SObject fields by name. Obviously a drawback for some use cases, but in your case it might be preferable? Example from the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/apex_api.pdf)

```
SObject account = new com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.wsc.SObject();
account.setType("Account");
account.setField("Name","myAccount");
account.setField("XID1__c", "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Java, you can use the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

A quick google found [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/) blog post which gives you a brief example. There are lots out there.